# Emailing pics from icloud photostream

Tags: email, graphics, photo-stream

I'm afraid I'm not very wised up technically.  I have taken pics on my ipad.  They have synced to my pc, in the icloud photostream, where I can view them.  I want to attach some of them to an email, using my normal email service.  Can I do that?

Comment: Did you install the iCloud stuff on your PC? You will be able to open Photostream as a folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can view them in iPhoto  !

In the left column there should be an item "Photostream" if you synced your account with the iCloud account.